# Problem with reading multiple files parallel using multiple processes: pipe(), for() and wait() in C

Tags: c, pipe

The purpose of the code is to find total of all integers in multiple files by calculating the sum of every file in parallel. 
Is there any problem with my pipe because the final result is always 0?

<sup>*Code copied from updated [Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I6V_2qrdC7Ln357Z3PUKf5S3205ocazmmW62aD7oreY/edit?usp=sharing) referenced in comments.*</sup>

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   double A[2], B[2];
   double count;
   int i = 1;
   double num;
   double sum = 0;
   int fd1[argc][2];
   double total = 0;
   int num_files = argc - 1;
   double ssum, res;

   for (i = 1; i <= num_files; i++) {
       pipe(fd1[i]);
   }
   for (i = 1; i <= num_files; i++) {
       int pid = fork();
       if (pid == 0) {
           FILE *fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
           printf("Processing file named %s\n", argv[i]);
           if (fp == NULL) {
               printf("File is empty %s\n", argv[i]);
               exit(1);
           }
           while ((res = fscanf(fp, "%lf", &num) != EOF)) {
               A[0] +=num;
               A[1]++;
           }
           fclose(fp);
           write(fd1[i][1], &A, (sizeof(A) +1));
           exit(0);
       } else
           wait(NULL);
   }
   for (i = 1; i <= num_files; i++) {
       read(fd1[i][0], &B, 50);
       if (B[1] == 0){
           printf("Error\n");
           exit(0);
       }

       ssum += B[0];
       count+= B[1];
   }
   printf("%lf\n", ssum / count);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not doing it in parallel, because the parent waits for each child to exit before repeating the loop and starting the next child.

Comment: If you want to do them in parallel, you need two loops: One loop that creates all the child processes, and another loop that reads from the pipe.

Comment: Where is the code that creates the pipe? You also have an unmatched `}` at the end.

Comment: What is `c = 0;` for?

Comment: @Barmar Can you show it in the actual code? Actually the code is to calculate the avg of all files so I have some extra variable. I pasted all my code but somehow it was cut off. The full code is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I6V_2qrdC7Ln357Z3PUKf5S3205ocazmmW62aD7oreY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You also have the problem that the children, after reading from the file and writing to the pipe, will go and fork more grandchildren to do the same, which is probably not what you want.  You'll end up with n(n-1)/2 decendents all reading the file when you probably only intended n

Comment: You need to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
Your code is too minimal — it is missing crucial information.  You also don't close the files you  open in the child.  At one level, not a huge crime if the child is about to exit.  Unfortunately, your child process doesn't exit, it goes on to process the next file too — so many if the files are processed multiple times.  You have a number of problems to deal with!

Comment: I've copied your code from the Google Doc — goodness only knows what the trouble was.  Note that there are 7 unused variables in the code (it isn't minimal).  There is no call to `pipe()` — it is also sub-minimal.  I'd recommend writing a program that doesn't attempt to fork but that does open each file on the command line, sum it, and prints the sum.  Make sure that code is in a function that takes, I suggest, the filename as the argument.  Get that working cleanly — closing the file, etc.  Then add the code to fork children which each call the function that you know works. _[continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ The children should write to standard output; your multiprocess code will ensure that the child has standard output going to the pipe before you call the function that does the summing.  You can then easily arrange for the parent process to launch all the children, and then read responses until there's no more to read.  It can also use `waitpid()` with `WNOHANG` to collect the status information from what will otherwise be zombie child processes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I redo it, and that is what I have right now. But somehow it return always double the actual sum, as well as I can only process 1 file, if there are 2 files, it will run infinitely. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I6V_2qrdC7Ln357Z3PUKf5S3205ocazmmW62aD7oreY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

<sup>The question says "sum of integers", but that leaves open the question "then why on earth is the code using `double` values everywhere"?  This answer assumes the data should be floating-point values, but it will work equivalently with integer data.  The examples could be reworked to use integer data.  However, it would be more sensible to revise the code so that it counts and sums using integers — unless the files are going to be so big that integers (e.g. `unsigned long long`) can no longer hold the values accurately.  At that point, there might be some value in using `double`, but it gets decidedly tricky — and it is very unlikely to be a problem.</sup>

You're getting closer, but you're still not initializing everything that needs initializing, you still have unused variables, you still aren't running the sums in parallel.  Here's some code with those problems fixed.  It also reports on the sum, count and mean in each child; it reports the overall sum and count as well as the overall mean. This helps with the verification.  The child messages include their PID.  The code closes the unused ends of the pipes, and closes the used ends when they're finished with.  I've also localized the variables much more.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd[argc][2];

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        pipe(fd[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            double A[2] = { 0.0, 0.0 };
            FILE *fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
            close(fd[i][0]);
            printf("%d: Processing file named %s\n", (int)getpid(), argv[i]);
            if (fp == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%d: File is empty %s\n", (int)getpid(), argv[i]);
                exit(1);
            }
            double num;
            while (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &num) == 1)
            {
                A[0] += num;
                A[1]++;
            }
            fclose(fp);
            write(fd[i][1], &A, sizeof(A));
            printf("%d: (%lg / %lg) = %lg\n", (int)getpid(), A[0], A[1], A[0] / A[1]);
            close(fd[i][1]);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
            close(fd[i][1]);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        int status;
        int corpse = wait(&status);
        if (corpse == -1)
            break;
        printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    }

    double count = 0.0;
    double ssum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        double B[2];
        read(fd[i][0], &B, sizeof(B));
        if (B[1] == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading pipe %d\n", i);
            exit(0);
        }
        ssum += B[0];
        count += B[1];
        close(fd[i][0]);
    }

    printf("(%lg / %lg) = %lf\n", ssum, count, ssum / count);
    return 0;
}
```

I created 10 files with a random number of lines between 10 and 20 in each, with a single number in the range 10 to 100 on it.  That's too much information to show here.  The program was `pipe29` created from `pipe29.c`.

```
$ pipe29 data.?
27911: Processing file named data.0
27912: Processing file named data.1
27913: Processing file named data.2
27912: (675 / 12) = 56.25
27911: (937.1 / 17) = 55.1235
27913: (792.9 / 13) = 60.9923
27914: Processing file named data.3
27915: Processing file named data.4
27915: (1051.8 / 18) = 58.4333
27914: (659.1 / 12) = 54.925
27916: Processing file named data.5
27917: Processing file named data.6
27916: (756.5 / 12) = 63.0417
27918: Processing file named data.7
27917: (1153.5 / 20) = 57.675
Child 27915 exited with status 0x0000
Child 27914 exited with status 0x0000
Child 27916 exited with status 0x0000
Child 27913 exited with status 0x0000
Child 27917 exited with status 0x0000
Child 27912 exited with status 0x0000
Child 27911 exited with status 0x0000
27919: Processing file named data.8
27918: (986.6 / 16) = 61.6625
Child 27918 exited with status 0x0000
27920: Processing file named data.9
27919: (1093 / 19) = 57.5263
27920: (1314 / 19) = 69.1579
Child 27919 exited with status 0x0000
Child 27920 exited with status 0x0000
(9419.5 / 158) = 59.617089
$
```

I ran a statistics program on the files and it gave:

```
$ pstats data.?
# Count    = 158
# Sum(x1)  =  9.419500e+03
# Sum(x2)  =  6.619076e+05
# Mean     =  5.961709e+01
# Std Dev  =  2.528115e+01 (sample)
# Variance =  6.391366e+02 (sample)
# Min      =  1.080000e+01
# Max      =  1.000000e+02
$
```

The sum, count and average agrees, which is reassuring.  It's interesting that one of the files manages to contain `100.0` (the maximum reported by `pstats`).
Given the range of the data, you'd expect a mean close to 60, and tht's what is calculated.

Note that it would be both permissible and sensible to use one pipe.  The messages that the children write are small enough that they'll be written atomically — so different children will not interfere with each other's data on the pipe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd[2];

    pipe(fd);

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            double A[2] = { 0.0, 0.0 };
            FILE *fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
            close(fd[0]);
            printf("%d: Processing file named %s\n", (int)getpid(), argv[i]);
            if (fp == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%d: File is empty %s\n", (int)getpid(), argv[i]);
                exit(1);
            }
            double num;
            while (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &num) == 1)
            {
                A[0] += num;
                A[1]++;
            }
            fclose(fp);
            write(fd[1], &A, sizeof(A));
            printf("%d: (%lg / %lg) = %lg\n", (int)getpid(), A[0], A[1], A[0] / A[1]);
            close(fd[1]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    close(fd[1]);

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        int status;
        int corpse = wait(&status);
        if (corpse == -1)
            break;
        printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    }

    double count = 0.0;
    double ssum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        double B[2];
        read(fd[0], &B, sizeof(B));
        if (B[1] == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading pipe %d\n", i);
            exit(0);
        }
        ssum += B[0];
        count += B[1];
        printf("%d: (%lg / %lg) = %lg\n", (int)getpid(), B[0], B[1], B[0] / B[1]);
    }
    close(fd[0]);

    printf("(%lg / %lg) = %lf\n", ssum, count, ssum / count);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ pipe31 data.?
27965: Processing file named data.0
27966: Processing file named data.1
27967: Processing file named data.2
27966: (675 / 12) = 56.25
27965: (937.1 / 17) = 55.1235
27968: Processing file named data.3
27967: (792.9 / 13) = 60.9923
27968: (659.1 / 12) = 54.925
27969: Processing file named data.4
27970: Processing file named data.5
27969: (1051.8 / 18) = 58.4333
27970: (756.5 / 12) = 63.0417
27971: Processing file named data.6
27972: Processing file named data.7
27971: (1153.5 / 20) = 57.675
27972: (986.6 / 16) = 61.6625
Child 27970 exited with status 0x0000
Child 27969 exited with status 0x0000
Child 27968 exited with status 0x0000
Child 27967 exited with status 0x0000
Child 27966 exited with status 0x0000
Child 27965 exited with status 0x0000
27973: Processing file named data.8
Child 27972 exited with status 0x0000
Child 27971 exited with status 0x0000
27974: Processing file named data.9
27973: (1093 / 19) = 57.5263
Child 27973 exited with status 0x0000
27974: (1314 / 19) = 69.1579
Child 27974 exited with status 0x0000
27964: (675 / 12) = 56.25
27964: (937.1 / 17) = 55.1235
27964: (792.9 / 13) = 60.9923
27964: (659.1 / 12) = 54.925
27964: (1051.8 / 18) = 58.4333
27964: (756.5 / 12) = 63.0417
27964: (1153.5 / 20) = 57.675
27964: (986.6 / 16) = 61.6625
27964: (1093 / 19) = 57.5263
27964: (1314 / 19) = 69.1579
(9419.5 / 158) = 59.617089
$
```

All the data printing is consistent still, which is reassuring.